# What could resolve a "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null" error without changing core functionality?

Tags: dart

Learning from an older project. Precisely looking to retrieve details from a real time database as well. The problem description is "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null".

Retrieving details from a Firebase real time database is the expectation. It does seem however that the code I'm learning from is slightly out outdated.

This is part of the code :

```dart
Future<void> retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId, BuildContext context) async {

  try {
    DatabaseReference newRequestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests");
    DatabaseEvent databaseEvent = await newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId).once();
    final data = databaseEvent.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;

    if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {

      assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"));
      assetsAudioPlayer.play();
      RideRequest rideRequest = RideRequest(data);
      double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
      double pickUpLocationLng = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString());
      String? pickUpAddress = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['pickup_address'].toString());
      double? dropOffLocationLat = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['dropoff']['latitude'].toString());
      double? dropOffLocationLng = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['dropoff']['longitude'].toString());
      String dropOffAddress = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['dropoff_address'].toString());
      String? paymentMethod = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['payment_method'].toString());
```

Comment: To do what the code used to do, but be null-safety compatible (I won't say "safe"), you need to add a `!` after each expression which might be null, but was assumed to not be so in the original code. In this case it's just before *every* `[` character, so `...snapshot.value!['pickup']!['latitude']...`, etc.

A much bigger rewrite would be a better choice in the long run. This is not well structured code. Far too much repetition.

Comment: Learning . After adding a ! , after every [ character, I'm soon led into a "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type Object" Error. What resolves this? And how can I avoid it in another case ?

Comment: The `!` should go *before* the `[`s ... which is after the previous nullable expression that the index operator is being used on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {

  assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"));
  assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  RideRequest rideRequest = RideRequest(data);
  double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
```

Between the moment you check whether `databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null` and the momoent you use it in `double.parse(databaseEvent.snapshot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString())` it is possible for `databaseEvent.snapshot.value` to change values (think multi-threading or event driven code). So the check doesn't help prevent the error later.

The simplest fix is to assign the value to a local variable and perform all operations on that:

```
...
final data = databaseEvent.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;
final value = databaseEvent.snapshot.value;

if (value != null) {
  assetsAudioPlayer.open(Audio("sounds/alert.mp3"));
  assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  RideRequest rideRequest = RideRequest(data);
  double pickUpLocationLat = double.parse(value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
  ...
```

The risk of `value` suddenly becoming null after you check is now gone, since it's a local variable.